# Are there any commutative rings in which no nonzero prime ideal is finitely generated?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, finitely-generated

> Are there any commutative rings in which no nonzero prime ideal is finitely generated?

I feel like the example (or proof of impossibility) ought to be obvious, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Fields, but that's just vacuously true. I suppose you want to discount those?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard example is $R := k[x_1, x_2, \ldots]/(x_1^2, x_2^2, \ldots)$. Then $R$ has a single prime ideal $\mathfrak{m} = (x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ which is not finitely generated ($\mathfrak{m}$ is the only prime since it is maximal, but every prime ideal of $R$ must contain $x_1^2, x_2^2, \ldots$ and hence $\mathfrak{m}$).

Comment: Man, I'm pretty sure I've asked questions before where that was the relevant example.  I just need to get that ring tattooed on my arm or something...

Comment: I generally am not very fond of tattoos, but in your case I'll make an exception!